# How to use PubSub subscription type 'write to Bigquery' write metadata only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement to save the metadata from a pubSub message to a BigQuery table. I know I can use '**Write to BigQuery delivery type**' and select 'Write metadata' but this option forces me to create a BigQuery column called '*data*'. How can I save only the metadata information in a bigQuery table?

I tried explored dataFlow, but I can't find any example to extract the metadata info.
Thanks

[image]

I tried to remove the data column from the BigQuery table, but it seems like it's required.
I also tried to use dataFlow with UDF but the Java Script file only accepts the JSON payload, I can't find a way to get the metadata

Answer (score 1):

It appears the "data" field is required, as stated in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-bigquery-subscription#write-metadata) and is important as this is the message body.

> The data field is required for all destination BigQuery tables that don't select Use topic schema. If the field is of type JSON, then the message body must be valid JSON.

I also tried to look for other answer, although different purpose but it seems data field is required.

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-bigquery-subscription#write-metadata